# What does a percentage symbol mean as part of a variable name?

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

I'm just looking at some VB.NET code and I came across this:

```
Dim var%
```

Later `var` is set to 0.

What's the purpose of the percent sign (`%`)?

(Google and SO search failed me)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Dim varname%` is ancient BASIC syntax for "`varname` is an integer". This has been around for a very long time in the history of the BASIC family, and is supported in Visual Basic.NET (although I, personally, wouldn't recommend it - it can be rather opaque, as discovered by you).

Comment: Great answer! Knowing this I was finally able to search more information about it. `"The last character of the name can be a dollar sign ($) to indicate a string variable or a percent sign (%) to indicate an integer variable."` Interesting, but I agree that it's a bit ambiguous in VB.NET.

Comment: @RowanFreeman I agree. It's an interesting historical artefact, but in VB.NET it's plain confusing to people like me who weren't around back then.

Answer (score 18):

It is shorthand for declaring "var" as of Type Integer, and has roots in the early, early days of BASIC (yes...old-school DOS BASIC).

So this:

```
Dim var%
```

is equivalent to:

```
Dim var As Integer
```

Here is the actual MS documentation:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191713

```
      %                 Integer
      &                 Long
      !                 Single
      #                 Double
      $                 String
      @                 Currency
```

Answer (score 5):

Putting a % sign at the end of the variable name in Visual Basic indicates that it is an integer. This was used by programmers in the old VB days, I am not sure why it is still present in VB.NET. Don't use it in new code, for all you know it might be gone in future versions of VB.NET.

& : Long

% : Integer

'# : Double

! : Single

@ : Decimal

$ : String