# Why some variables names have '%' or '$' symbol at the end in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, naming-conventions

Recently i have been studying one vb.net project and it was written in vs 2005.

I came across a variables that were **ending** with **'`%`' and '`$`'.**

My question is **What is the need and significance of it, I tried googling it but found no trace for the query?**

here are some lines of code from the project:

```
Public Sub SaveSettings(ByVal Cntl As Control, ByVal File$)
        FileNo = FOpen(File, OpenMode.Output)
        If FileNo = -1 Then Throw New System.Exception("File - " + File + " cannot be opened for writing!")
        BuildHashTable(Cntl)
        SaveControls(Cntl)
        FClose(FileNo)
    End Sub
```

and

```
Dim i%, s$, t$
```

The variables are File$, i%, s$ and t$.

I am quite foreign to VB6, so i don't know if it is having any relation with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a percentage symbol mean as part of a variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454621/what-does-a-percentage-symbol-mean-as-part-of-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that postfix characters were used in VB6 (and before) to declare the type of the variable.
They are still supported (as far as I know) in VB.NET to facilitate the transition from VB6 to VB.NET

[Here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s9cz43ek%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) a list of those characters

When a Type Character is present it should follow the name part. 
This was (at that time) a clever way to remind the programmer of the datatype of a variable, but nowadays (with Intellisense and smart compilers) I find them distracting and with no use. I remove them immediately (well I removed them also in VB6 so I am a little biased here)

Comment: Thank you it helped me clarifying my doubts.