# vb.net For loop in If statement - shorten the ElseIf

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

how to shorten this: 
Information: %WASHV% is a constant coming from an outer for loop an so is %loop%.

I tried to do a for loop in Elseif / also with new If statement but failed

Thanks.

code:

```
|If [%loop%] = "1" Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-2*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-3*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"
ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-4*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-5*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-6*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-7*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-8*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

ElseIf [%loop%] =96-(96-9*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
Return "True"

Else

Return "False“

End If|
```

Comment: Are you sure that's VB.NET?  I've never seen variables like `%loop%` in VB.NET....

Comment: It is vb in a different Programm that is using These % % defining tokens

Comment: What program? Without knowing how the tokens work, we may not be able to help. It's certainly not written using visual studio.

Comment: It is for an autosampler Software , assume that the %loop% runs from 1 - 96 and that % washv% is a constant value but can be changed by the User in advanve , dies this help ?

Comment: so [%loop%] is the loop index?

Comment: Exactly , because there is another for loop running around this One shown here , sorry for the Bad working examples .. It is annoying to get to unterstand the work someelse

Comment: Ah ok. Though if the language is not exactly the same as Microsoft's Visual Basic.Net then you should probably find a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Seems like you could use some basic algebra here to factor out some of those constants and get it down to as few as three If/Else statements, before even running a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is VB.Net, the simplification can be done like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 9
    If [%loop%] =96-(96-i*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
        Return "True"
    End If
Next

Return If([%loop%] = "1", "True", "False")
```

Yet, more pressing matter is to find out the use of %loop% and %WASHV%.

The use of % in the rightside of VB.Net variable during initialization indicates it is an integer:

```
Dim a% 'integer
```

Check this: [What does a percentage symbol mean as part of a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454621/what-does-a-percentage-symbol-mean-as-part-of-a-variable-name)

There are many other symbols like $, &, !, @, and # too.

But the left %, I know not.

It looks more like query language to me, something like this:

```
... where s like '%loop%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd variables aside, it looks like a pretty simple loop.  The Return statement will automatically exit the loop and whatever function you are in once reached and the loop will cease.  If the loop completes then your Else condition is reached.

```
If [%loop%] = "1" Then
    Return "True"
End If

For i As Integer = 1 To 9

    If [%loop%] =96-(96-i*round([5000/%WASHV%])) Then
        Return "True"
    End If

Next

Return "False"
```

Comment: shouldn't the calculation be 96-(96-i*round([5000/%WASHV%])) or am i missing something? Cheers

Comment: it sure should.  i've edited to correct for that.  thanks.